# How to generate custom _id values for CLOUDANT database?

Tags: cloudant

I am trying to insert Employee record in cloudant using their Java API.

When I insert the record, Cloudant is generating its own _ID automatically. I would like to control generation of this _ID field as well.

I searched the API, but couldn't find anything like a SEQUENCE in RDBMS. Can someone give hint on how to achieve this?

Comment: Which java api are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Using the Cloudant Java library, use the `save` method to allow you to specify the id of your documents:

https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant#comcloudantclientapidatabasesaveobjectwritequorum

The underlying HTTP API is documented here:

https://docs.cloudant.com/document.html#documentCreate

Answer (score 0):

While creating your document if you pass _id within your JSON it will be created as per that. If _id is not present then it will be created automatically.

For example, This will create _id as you provide (AAA1)
{
    "_id":"AAA1",
    "fname":"Dimitry",
    "country":"India"
}

and this will generate _id automatically
{
    "fname":"Dimitry",
    "country":"India"
}